# Activerecord validate numericality with messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a validation which has a lower and upper limit. I need to specify a message for each of these limits but unsure how to do so.

```
numericality: {
  only_integer: true,
  less_than_or_equal_to: 100000000,
  greater_than_or_equal_to: 10000,
  message: 'must be more than or equal to 100'
}
```

The message should be relevant to the validation that failed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom validation for this. Have a look at this how to show different messages for each case.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations